# Why my AsyncTask doesn't finish?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've created an asynctask in my MapActivity, here it is:

```
class ReadLocations extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    GeoPoint apoint1;
    GeoPoint apoint2;
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> Locations = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(); 


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyMapLocationActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("DONE");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        return null; 
    }


    protected void onPostExecute() {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

I'm trying to execute it this way:

```
public class MyMapLocationActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;  
private ProgressDialog eDialog;  


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

ReadLocations Read = new ReadLocations();
Read.execute();

 ...
```

My controlling dialog never disappears - it seems like my onPostExecute method is not called - why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becoz, your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` have not argument.  which is return by `doInBackground()` .

**SO override correctly both methods.**

Something like,

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {  // Return type of same as argument of onPostExecute() 
    return null; 
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) { // Add String argument in onPostExecute()
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

As possible of execution of `doInBackground()` is fast because there is no any other work implementation in it. only one return statement..

Comment: I'd also say, that if the signatures were correct, you wouldn't see the Dialog either, because its already being dismissed, before it could be drawn properly. You (the OP) should add some actual work or for testing a sleep in doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

You have not correctly overridden onPostExecute, the result parameter is missing

It should be something like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: And you should probably add the @Override annotation. It would have told you that something was wrong int the first place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse the best and the easiest way to override or implement methods of super classes correctly is:

1. Focus cursor on your `AsyncTask` body. Then `mouse right click`--> `source` --> `override/implement methods`.
2. Choose necessary methods.
3. Click OK. Methods will automatically add into your class.

Also you can generate constructors, getters/setters etc this way .